# where she stays in? stays?

Tags: prepositions

A singer always goes to a hotel whenever she goes on a world tour.

> The singer is particular about where she stays.
> The singer is particular about where she stays in.

Which is good?

Answer (score 1):

*where she stays* is correct.
The word *where* already means *in what place*. That makes *where she stays in* redundant and incorrect.

Comment: then don't you think 'in' makes the sentence more correct if I want to talk about 'hotel'?

Comment: It doesn't. However, you could say _about which hotel she stays in_. That's because _which_ doesn't imply 'place' in the way that _where_ does.

Comment: I do think this is partly a matter of dialect.  Do you also think "Where is she going to?" is redundant and incorrect?  It sounds reasonable to this NYC native English speaker.

Comment: @stangdon I don't think it adds anything to "Where is she going?", so to me it's redundant, though it doesn't sound as strange as "where she stays in". If it's how people speak, it's correct. Would you write it in something formal?